# While presenting ViewController application receives memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, avaudioplayer

Whenever tap song from table view it leads memory to 117 to 170 some time app crashes in device

**In table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath i wrote following code**

```
if([fileStatus isEqualToString:@"IN_LOCAL"])
{
  musicObject=[songManagerObject getSongForName:filename];
 [musicPlayerObject play:musicObject];
    [self presentViewController:[musicPlayerObject playerObj] animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

**Method Play**

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) AudioCoreViewController *playerObj;


-(void) play:(MusicBase *)mx;
{
    if([mx.fileType isEqualToString:@"mp3"])
    {
        playerObj=[AudioCoreViewController sharedAudioPlayer];
        [playerObj play:mx];  
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it cause the memory spike if you put [musicPlayerObject play:musicObject]; in the completion:^{//here//}

Comment: @Logan if i do like that am getting following error:'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target Because in play method only am filling the object in another class

Comment: Can you show the full code of `didSelectRow:`

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi didSelectRow:
if([fileStatus isEqualToString:@"IN_LOCAL"])
    {
      musicObject=[songManagerObject getSongForName:filename];
        NSLog(@"%@",musicObject.fileName);
     [musicPlayerObject play:musicObject];
        [self presentViewController:[musicPlayerObject playerObj] animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }

Comment: Pls don't write code in the comment section. Edit your question with that patch.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi check now it is ok ?

Comment: what is that line suggest `[self presentViewController:[musicPlayerObject playerObj] animated:YES completion:^{}];`?

Comment: Player * musicPlayerObject;
This is object for class Player here only we have method play in this class if it is MP3 loading Audioplayer in to playerobj @HimanshuJoshi

Comment: So why are you getting the value of `playerObj`. Simply do `[self presentViewController:musicPlayerObject animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi MusicplalyerObject is object of player class from there only we r loading viewController to player object Musicplayer obejct is not viewcontroller playerObj only view controller we cant directly pass nsobject in present view controller

Comment: This is confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([fileStatus isEqualToString:@"IN_LOCAL"]) { 
  musicObject=[songManagerObject getSongForName:filename];
  NSLog(@"%@",musicObject.fileName); 

  [self presentViewController:[musicPlayerObject playerObj] animated:YES completion:^{
    [musicPlayerObject play:musicObject]; 
   }]; 
}
```